# How to I convert bytes to float in big query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am working with data stored as a very long base64 encoded string in Big Query and trying to substring out floating point numbers which are stored as IEE754 format. The best I've been able to achieve so far is a hex representation of the floating point number, is there any way to turn the bytes or hex value into a float?

I have been able to get a hex representation of the floating point number as follows,

to_hex(substring(from_base64(my_string),start_pos,length))